# How to make a For-loop

Tags: php, for-loop

How do I create a for-loop that prints only 2, 4, 6, 8?

I've been looking around everywhere but cannot find it. It's for school haha!

Comment: Hey guys, it's for learning, homework. You are contra productive when showing solutions ;)

Comment: Learn about integer operators like mod % and /. A bit of logic with those inside your for and you will have it in no time.

Comment: You looked around "everywhere"? How long did that take? 1 sec.? ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
for ($x=2; $x<=8; $x+=2)
  {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this

for($i=1;$i<=8;$i++){

echo $i*2;
if($i==8){

break;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var a = 2; a<=8;a++){
console.log(a);
a = a+1;
```

}

Is this you're looking for?